# Hello everyone, i created this class that should return a list of contacts, but when i execute the code i get an empty list, could anyone help me plz?

Tags: apex

```java
public class ContactSearch {
    public static List<Contact>  searchForContacts (String  s1, String s2) {
        List<Contact> cont = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE (LastName LIKE 's1' AND MailingPostalCode LIKE 's2')];
        return cont;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! It'd be helpful to know what the values of `s1` and `s2` you're using. You could also test your query in the "Query Editor" tab of the Developer Console with a little modification.

Comment: I've also edited your question so that the code is properly formatted (and shows up as a code block), which makes it easier for most people to read.

Comment: thank you! it's working now , it was just a syntax error in the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the input values, you need to use a binding statement. To do this, prefix the code to evaluate (in this case, s1 and s2) with a colon (`:`):

```
[SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE (LastName LIKE :s1 AND MailingPostalCode LIKE :s2)]
```

If you use quotes, as you have, you are trying to find the literal values 's1' and 's2'.

Comment: hello!it worked, it's the first time i use Apex i had no idea, thank you for your help!